# cognito app domain not working with federated sign in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, google-signin, federated

I am getting this error ❌ `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`
when browser send request to:

`https://<my-domain>.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fflight&response_type=code&client_id=1qlendigv0c47prue7nr7qu0o6&identity_provider=Google&scope=phone%20email%20openid%20profile%20aws.cognito.signin.user.admin&state=<place-holder>&code_challenge=<place-holder>&code_challenge_method=S256`

with this user pool, email and password login works well but federated sign in is causing this error `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. I think that there may be some error in domain of app client

I am unable to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, there was error in my domain for amplify config object:

I was missing `auth` in domain for config object

`<my-domain>.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com` <==== wrong

`<my-domain>.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com` <==== correct